# Why does Future.get() method NOT return anything after shutdownNow() method is called?

Tags: java, executorservice

This class hangs at Future.get() method after executing ExecutorService.shutdownNow() called. I don't know what i am making mistake.

This class creates fixed thread pool and it is timing out after 5 seconds. If 5 consecutive error happens, this will call shutdownNow().

```
 public class TestExecutor {

private AtomicInteger mThresholdCount = new AtomicInteger();
// Default error threshold limit
private int mThresholdLimit = 5;

private ExecutorService executor;

private ThreadPool pool;

public TestExecutor() {
    option2();
}   

private void option2() {
    executor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(2);
    Collection<Future<String>> runnableList = new ArrayList<Future<String>>();
    for (int count = 0; count <= 10; count++) {
        MyCallable runnable = new MyCallable(count);
        runnableList.add(executor.submit(runnable));
    }
    for (Future<String> future : runnableList) {
        try {
            System.out.println("Before Get");
            future.get();
            System.out.println("After Get");
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    executor.shutdown();
}   

public static void main(String[] args) {
    new TestExecutor();
}

private class TimeOutTask extends TimerTask {
    private Thread t;

    public TimeOutTask(Thread t) {
        this.t = t;
    }

    public void run() {
        if (t != null && t.isAlive()) {
            t.interrupt();
        }
    }
}

private class MyCallable implements Callable<String> {

    private int count = 0;
    private Timer timer = new Timer(true);

    public MyCallable(int count) {
        this.count = count;
    }

    @Override
    public String call() {
        try {
            System.out.println("Started Processing " + count);
            timer.schedule(new TimeOutTask(Thread.currentThread()), 5000);
            Thread.sleep(100000);
            System.out.println("Completed processing " + count);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("Error while processing:" + count);
            if (mThresholdCount.incrementAndGet() == mThresholdLimit) {
                System.out.println("while processing:" + count
                        + " Reached maximum error threshold limit! "
                        + "Requested to stop the process.");
                if (executor != null) {
                    executor.shutdownNow();
                    System.out.println("Shut down now");
                }

            }
        }
        return String.valueOf(count);
    }
}
```

}

Please help me understanding why get() is hanging here after 5 threads continuously interrupted and shutdownNow() is called?

Comment: The code you've given *doesn't* call `shutdownNow`. Please give a short but *complete* example which actually demonstrates what you're talking about.

Comment: MyCallable class call() method calls executor.shutdownNow();, if there is an exception and error threshold limit is equals to 5

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because the Callables at the end of the list never actually get executed, and thus, never complete (you have 2 threads and 10 tasks).  You'll notice that the `shutdownNow()` method returns a List of Runnables which never get executed.  You should probably do something meaningful with those.